# How to properly test the login and logout functionality of a web application?

Tags: selenium, authentication, web-applications, phpunit

Is there a standard way to test the login and logout functionality of a web application. I know you should test the underlying functionality at the class level and probably use Selenium to test the process from beginning to end from the browser. I just wonder if there are patterns for testing authentication maybe even access control.